# How to include integer constraint in MatLab's 'linprog( )' function?

Tags: matlab, optimization, linear-programming

So I'm using linprog on matlab in order to solve an optimization problem and one of the constraints is that all the numbers are multiples of 0.5 or in other terms, every number doubled is an integer. 
Because of the form that all the constraints must be in (they must all be in linear equations), I'm struggling to find a way to set this rule as a constraint.

How can I write a constraint to linprog to ensure all the numbers in the return array are multiples of 0.5?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html?refresh=true ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using intlinprog.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html

For this, you would have to declare an integer variable x_int.

If x was your initial continuous variable, then the following constraint ensures that x is always a multiple of 0.5

2x = x_int